# SmtpClient.SendMailAsync causes deadlock when throwing a specific exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-identity, smtpclient

I'm trying to set up email confirmation for an ASP.NET MVC5 website, based on the example AccountController from the VS2013 project template. I've implemented the `IIdentityMessageService` using `SmtpClient`, trying to keep it as simple as possible:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        using(var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage("some.guy@company.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

The controller code that is calling it is straight from the template (extracted into a separate action since I wanted to exclude other possible causes):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAsyncEmail()
{
    Guid userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    
    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = userId, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userId, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

    return View();
}
```

However I'm getting odd behavior when the mail fails to send, but only in one specific instance, when the host is somehow unreachable. Example config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="unreachablehost" defaultCredentials="true" port="25" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

In that case, the request appears to deadlock, never returning anything to the client. If the mail fails to send for any other reason (e.g. host actively refuses connection) the exception is handled normally and I get a YSOD.

Looking at the Windows event logs, it seems that an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown around the same timeframe, with the message "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."; I get that same message in a YSOD if I try to catch the `SmtpException` in the controller and return a `ViewResult` in the catch block. So I figure the `await`-ed operation fails to complete in either case.

As far as I can tell, I am following all the async/await best practices as outlined in other posts on SO (e.g. [HttpClient.GetAsync(...) never returns when using await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)), mainly "using async/await all the way up". I've also tried using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, with no change. Since the code deadlocks only if a specific exception is thrown, I figure the general pattern is correct for most cases, but something is happening internally that makes it incorrect in that case; but since I'm pretty new to concurrent programming, I've a feeling I could be wrong.

Is there something I'm doing wrong ? I can always use a synchronous call (ie. `SmtpClient.Send()`) in the SendAsync method, but it feels like this should work as is.

Comment: Take a look at [Stephen Cleary's answer on catching an exception on a void method(`SendMailAsync`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7350534/209259).  Async Void Methods are problem childs sometimes.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I don't see any `async void`  methods in the sample (either implemented or called) - did you mean some particular line?

Comment: As workaround you may try to manually resolve the host and fail earlier... Also look at [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,b9a40a3be18a4d58) for insights - hopefully it would be helpful...

Comment: @regexen: Do you have [`httpRuntime.targetFramework` set to `4.5` in your `web.config`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx)?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yup.

Comment: I remember a related question with a workaround... there it is: [Sending async mail from SignalR hub](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24377081)

Comment: @Noseratio: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that solution, and now the exception seems to be swallowed by the `IgnoreSynchronizationContext`, and the controller method returns as if nothing went wrong. Since I can't handle faults in that case, it doesn't fix it for me.

Comment: @regexen, try my `WithNoContext` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24386344/1768303), see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Noseratio: Seems to work the same way; the exception is not caught outside the helper method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Noseratio and Stephen!, fixed the same issue for me...Now I have to learn more about EAP

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this implementation, just use `client.SendMailExAsync` instead of `client.SendMailAsync`. Let us know if it makes any difference:

```
public static class SendMailEx
{
    public static Task SendMailExAsync(
        this System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient @this,
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message,
        CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // use Task.Run to negate SynchronizationContext
        return Task.Run(() => SendMailExImplAsync(@this, message, token));
    }

    private static async Task SendMailExImplAsync(
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client, 
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message, 
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        System.Net.Mail.SendCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
        Action unsubscribe = () => client.SendCompleted -= handler;

        handler = async (s, e) =>
        {
            unsubscribe();

            // a hack to complete the handler asynchronously
            await Task.Yield(); 

            if (e.UserState != tcs)
                tcs.TrySetException(new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected UserState"));
            else if (e.Cancelled)
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else if (e.Error != null)
                tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        };

        client.SendCompleted += handler;
        try
        {
            client.SendAsync(message, tcs);
            using (token.Register(() => client.SendAsyncCancel(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
            {
                await tcs.Task;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That one works; the exception is caught as one would normally expect, bubbles up the call stack and I get a YSOD. Seems like a whole lot of code to do something that seemed so simple (!), but I can see how it can get complicated fast. Anyway marking as accepted since it does solve it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Glad it works; it's a typical `Task`-based wrapper over [EAP pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I wonder if it still would work *without* `await Task.Yield()`, maybe you could give it a try.

Comment: Seems to work without the `Task.Yield`, according to a quick test.

Comment: @regexen, in which case, the `handler` doesn't need to be async, apparently.

Comment: So is there a bug in SmtpClient that this code works around?

Comment: @pettys, there might a bug but I couldn't spot it from the first glance.

Comment: Why don't you use `Task.Run(async () => await SendMailExImplAsync(@this, message, token));`? (By your current implementation you're still 'wasting' a thread while doing the IO operation, The way I suggested you're freeing up the thread until IO operation is completed)

Comment: *By your current implementation you're still 'wasting' a thread while doing the IO operation...* @BornToCode I'm not. `Task.Run(() => FuncAsync())` is basically doing the same as  `Task.Run(async () => await FuncAsync())` but without added async state machine micro-overhead. In both cases, the same [`Task.Run` override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) is used.

Comment: But without await the thread is held and not released to the thread pool even while you're waiting for the IO operation of sending the email.

Comment: @BornToCode, no `Task.Run` won't block anything for functions that return a `Task` like `SendMailExImplAsync` (unless such function has a blocking wait inside, which mine doesn't).  If you like to learn more, have a look at [`Task.Run` implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Task.cs,c3e0ffe470f08b7b).

Comment: This appears to work for the same issue I was experiencing, however it seems to only time-out and return after a full 5 minutes - even though the TimeOut on the SmtpClient is set to 60000. Is there any way to reduce the time-out?

Comment: @Gary, create a [`CancellationTokenSource` with timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource__ctor_System_Int32_) you want and pass its token to `SendMailExImplAsync`

Comment: @noseratio. Perfect, this seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 3):

On .Net 8 this did not solve my issue, and I did not see any exceptions being thrown either.

Finally adding

```
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Seems to fix some underlying issue...

Comment: [`SmtpClient` is deprecated on modern .NET anyway](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md), so you shouldn't be using it on .NET 8.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Thanks, I was not aware of that. It is kind of hidden away in the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-8.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue#remarks) of the docs. They should mark the class with an obsolete attribute, that way it would be noticed.