# SendMailAsync fails on 20th email, but non-async version works

Tags: c#, sendmail, asp.net-core-6.0

When trying to call SendMailAsync it fails after 20 emails. However, the non-async version of the call works. The error message is: "The server response was: 4.3.2 The maximum number of concurrent server connections has exceeded a per-source limit, closing transmission channel". Could anyone advise please?

```
    public SmtpClient SetupEMail()
    {
        return new SmtpClient("mail")
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mailuser", "mailpassword")
        };
    }


    public async Task SendEmails()
    {
        var Mail = new MailMessage("from@address.com", "test@address.com", "Test Subject", "Test body");

        using (var client = _email.SetupEMail())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                Mail.To.Clear();
                Mail.To.Add((i % 2 == 0 ? "test1@address.com" : "test2@address.com"));
                Mail.Subject = $"{i}";
                Mail.Body = $"{i}";
                await client.SendMailAsync(Mail); // async method not work
                client.Send(Mail); // works fine

            }

        };

    }
```

Comment: The error implies that you're making too many connections to the mail server.  Is `SendEmails()` being awaited?  Is what calls it being awaited?  It sounds like somewhere in your code you are sending rapid requests to the mail server, and it's rejecting them.

Comment: Is there a reason you are reusing the same `MailMessage` object? Seems a lot safer to me to create a new one for each email you send. Not sure this will solve you problem.

Comment: @David yeah i agree, the call to SendEmails() is being awaited

Comment: @DavidG my thinking was efficiency. I've tried your suggestion and still provides the same error. I thought it would be more effiecient setting it up once, due to the garbage collection overhead and delay.

Comment: Try creating the `SmtpClient` _inside_ the `for` loop so it closes the connection to the server after each mail.

Comment: I am here because I have the same problem, even when using SendMail, not even using SendMailAsync, and I am creating new MailMessage and SmtpClient objects each time.  I also tried Sleep(200) after each one and it still happens (intermittently).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **SmtpClient** from **System.Net.Mail** then it is known issue, SendMailAsync doesn't recycle properly connections => you reach to maximum allowed open connection (may vary between different mail servers).

See similar issue here

[SmtpClient.SendMailAsync method is hanging when sending a big amount of mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581992/smtpclient-sendmailasync-method-is-hanging-when-sending-a-big-amount-of-mails/54633829#54633829)

This library is obsolete and **MailKit** is the right replacement for it.

See details here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-8.0