# C# Async/Await SmtpClient.SendMailAsync

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, async-await

I have written a simple class for me to send reports which works well, however I now need to incorporate a log to check whether the send was successful or not.

A quick brief on my app: It has a main form that you can manually run the reports via buttons and if the app is run from the command line then the form is hidden.

When the form is shown the `SmtpClient.SendComplete` event fires, but when the form is hidden it does not and also doesn't send the email. I have tried every which way to get it to work.

```
public static async Task SendAsync(string sendTo, string subject, string body = "", string attachment = "")
{
#if (DEBUG)
    // If in DEBUG mode then send reports to lee.
    sendTo = "developer";
#endif
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.server", 587)
        { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password") };
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage
        { From = new MailAddress("mailFrom") };
        message.To.Add(sendTo);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment))
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
        client.SendCompleted += (s,e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    Logger.FileLog(message.Subject, e.Error.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.FileLog(message.Subject, "Message Sent");
                }
                client.Dispose();
                message.Dispose();
            };
        Logger.FileLog(_subject, "Running Async");
        await client.SendMailAsync(message);

        Logger.FileLog(_subject, "Finished");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.FileLog(subject, $"Error {e.HResult}, {e.Message}, {e.InnerException.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

I have tried `async Task`, `async void`, `SendAsync`, `SendMailAsync`, loops to wait for a callback.

Some of the logging is there just so I can see how far it got when running from the command line and it only ever gets as far as "Running Async" which is before it tries to send the email.

The code for detecting whether to show or hide the form as requested, the original project was written in VB, the above code is in a class library which was working until I tried to run Async.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
        Visible = False
        RunSilent = True
        ParseCommandLine()
        Close()
    Else
        'Update to add from db, XML or Excel
        Dim t As Task = Task.Run(
            Sub()
                LoadReports()
            End Sub)
        t.Wait()
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28445791/1768303) helps.

Comment: It might help if you show us the logic around detecting if it is running from the console and hiding the form.

Comment: The described behavior may be due to a deadlock but without a [mcve], I can't say for sure

Comment: Investigate the parse command method and see if you are mixing async and blocking calls

Comment: thanks, you've all given me something to look at, I will report back what I find.

Comment: Okay, I have stepped through running the command line, the app closes at this line `await client.SendMailAsync(message);` which leads me to the UI thread closing, I'm new to async programming, how do I hold the UI thread open?

Comment: How and where is the `SendAsync` method being called?

Comment: You close right after processing command line, so chances are that you are not awaiting the method and `Close` is being invoked before the email can be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close right after processing command line, so chances are that you are not awaiting the method and `Close` is being invoked before the email can be sent.

assuming `ParseCommandLine` and `LoadReports` are async functions then you should await them in the event handler

```vb
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
        Visible = False
        RunSilent = True
        Await ParseCommandLine() 'wait for task to complete then close
        Close()
    Else
        'Update to add from db, XML or Excel
        Await LoadReports()
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the removal of `.Wait()` blocking call that could cause deadlock when mixed with async calls.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I will look at all of the methods and make sure they all use async and await, didn't realise it would be this difficult when I started it:(

Comment: @LeeMorgan When choosing to use async/await, it tends to spread to the point where you tend to go async all the way. Once you get the hang of it, things tend to get easier.

Comment: Just so I am clear on it all, any method that calls an async method also needs to be async/await?

Comment: @LeeMorgan Yes, if you want to wait on said task. If you do not want to wait you can still call it from a non async method, but it will be running on a separate thread, which can lead to the behavior you are seeing with the close happening before it is desired.

Comment: Mega, not only have you answered my question but you have also helped me understand it some more.  I really appreciate your time and explanation.